# Error reading Kepler FITS file using astropy

Tags: python, astropy, fits

I was trying to read fits files from Kepler FITS files (Received from this URL https://archive.stsci.edu/pub/kepler/lightcurves/0007/000757076/) using astropy. Below are the set of commands I was trying to read the file:

```
from astropy.io import fits
fits_image_filename = fits.util.get_testdata_filepath(r'O:\MyWorks\keplar-test\kplr100000925-2009166043257_llc.fits')
```

But the above command produced this error:

[image]

I am not sure how to solve this error. My target is to read keplar data then plot this and/or convert this to CSV.

Comment: It says that it couldn't open the URL ``http://www.astropy.org/astropy-data/io/fits/tests/data/O:\\MyWorks\\...`` which seems reasonable.

Comment: But why should it open this URL, I have the fits file downloaded in my local system and also have astropy in my system.

Comment: `get_testdata_filepath` is for downloading and opening some sample files used for tests and demonstrations. It's not for opening arbitrary FITS files. You can see in the error message at the bottom of the traceback that it just appended your local filesystem path to the URL it downloads the same files from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This: `fits.util.get_testdata_filepath(r'O:\MyWorks\keplar-test\kplr100000925-2009166043257_llc.fits')` is not the correct function for opening a file.

You should use `fits.open('file.fits')`, or if this is table data, as you imply, `Table.read('file.fits')`

See the note at the top of the [FITS documentation](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/#opening-a-fits-file)

Comment: Additionally `fits.open` and its higher-level counterparts can open a URL directly IIRC

Answer (score 0):

```
%matplotlib inline
from astropy.io import fits
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

#My required file has been downloaded in the following path of my HD,
"~/projects/eclipsing_binary/A/mastDownload/HLSP/hlsp_qlp_tess_ffi_s0018-0000000346784049_tess_v01_llc/hlsp_qlp_tess_ffi_s0018-000000346784049_tess_v01_llc.fits". Using linux command open and see the list
of the files in the directory.

```
%cd ~/projects/eclipsing_binary/A/mastDownload/HLSP/
hlsp_qlp_tess_ffi_s0018-0000000346784049_tess_v01_llc/
%ls
```

#Now plot the required file in simple way,

```
import lightkurve as lk
file_r = 'hlsp_qlp_tess_ffi_s0018-0000000346784049_tess_v01_llc.fits'
lr = lk.read(file_r)
lr.plot()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).